# More specific than ReactNode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I defined props for a component:

```
interface HeaderProps{
  title: string;
  image: string;
  link: ReactNode;
}
```

'link' refers to another component, `<Link />`

So I define it as a ReactNode.

Is there anything more specific I can use instead of ReactNode? Like `typeof Link` or just `Link`?

Comment: Maybe `ReactNode<Link's prop interface/type>`

Comment: Not sure I got that. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing to Allow Only Specific Component

Since React.ReactElement<> accepts any type of element, you can also make it strictly to accepts some specific component type. Let’s say you have a Header component that should only works if it receives a Link component. You can type it as the following

```
//link interface

interface Link {
  link: string
}

const Link = ({ children }: Link) => <span>{children}</span>


Then in your interface HeaderProps

interface HeaderProps{
  title: string;
  image: string;
  link: ReactElement<Link>;
}

// Correct usage
<Header>
....
<Link>Some content</Link>

</Header>

// Wrong usage
<Header>
...
<Link>{true}</Link>

</Header>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked I just had to add 'typeof'. ReactElement<typeof Link>